# PHP code works locally but not on server (cPanel)

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code in my website to generate image albums without me having to manually create them:

```
<?php
$folder_path = 'assets/albums/album1/thumbnails/';
$num_files = glob($folder_path . "*.{jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
$folder = opendir($folder_path);

$folder_path_o = 'assets/albums/album1/';
$num_files_o = glob($folder_path_o . "*.{jpg,gif,png,bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
$folder_o = opendir($folder_path_o);

if($num_files > 0)
{
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($folder)) && ($file_o = readdir($folder_o))) {
        $file_path = $folder_path.$file;
        $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($file , PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        $file_path_o = $folder_path_o.$file_o;
        $extension_o = strtolower(pathinfo($file_o , PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

        if (($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp') && ($extension_o == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'gif' || $extension == 'bmp')) {
            ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo $file_path_o; ?>" data-lightbox="<?php echo $folder; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file_path; ?>" alt="<?php echo $album_name; ?>"></a></li>
            <?php
        }
    }
}
else {
    echo "the folder was empty";
}
closedir($folder);
?>
```

This code works perfectly on my localhost. However, when I upload it to the server (shared hosting on name.com with cPanel) it only seems to work partially:

- On localhost, it generates the whole album, displays all the images of the designated folders (`$folder_path` and `folder_path_o`).
- On the server, it returns only one image, not the whole folder (this leads me to believe this isn't a permissions related issue)

Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to check are the permissions of the folder the same as the oen of the picture? And I assume you are running this on a linux machine?

Comment: what versions of php are running to test and poduction servers (localhost and remote)?

Comment: wrap all in try {
    
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo  $e->getMessage();
} and prioved us error

Comment: @JRsz Folder and image permissions are the same.

Comment: @Peter Darmis Both are running php5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can check it, it has to do with the server itself, you can't make it sure.

```
switch ($_FILES['upfile']['error']) {
        case UPLOAD_ERR_OK:
            echo "Uploading success";
        case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        echo "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
    case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE:
        echo "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.";
    case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR:
        echo "Missing a temporary folder.";
    case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE:
        echo "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.";
    case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE:
        echo "Failed to write file to disk";


        default:
            throw new RuntimeException('Unknown errors.');
    }
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance (I've only just started out with php), but where should I put this code?

Comment: You can put it just after executing `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["...."]["tmp_name"], '/uploads/your.ext')`

Comment: I might just be totally blind, but I have no idea where to put the code. Just to be clear, there isn't really an uploading system in my code. I just put the images in folders on the server, and then use the above php to retrieve them and put them in the html code.